# Symfony 6.x - Attribute Route on versioned controller

Tags: php, symfony, controller

This is driving me crazy, maybe it's just one of those design issue that i'm not aware about but i don't feel like i'm doing anything bad here.

I have 2 controllers:

```php
namespace App\Controller;


use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;


#[Route('/demo/v1')]
class DemoV1Controller extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'demov1')]
    public function mySpecialRoute(Request $request)
    {

    }
}
```

and

```php
#[Route('/demo/v2')]
class DemoV2Controller extends DemoV1Controller
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'demov2')]
    public function mySpecialRoute(Request $request)
    {

    }
}
```

If i go on my cli and execute:

```
bin/console debug:route
```

It prints:

```
  demov1                                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /demo/v1/                               
  demov2                                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /demo/v2
```

Which is fine.

Now, i want to make V2 extend V1, and keep the same controller class name, just changing the namespace. So after creating the directory and adjusting the namespace accordingly i get this if i run again i get the same result as above. Now, i add another route to the V1 controller and go dump route again:

```
demov1_other                            ANY      ANY      ANY    /demo/v2/other
```

Now, this one pops out and i already have a strange feeling. So i go even further, and change V1->specialRoute function name to V1->specialRouteV1, same with V2. I dump route again:

```
  demov2                                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /demo/v2/                               
  demov1                                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /demo/v2/                               
  demov1_other                            ANY      ANY      ANY    /demo/v2/other
```

which is produced by this code:

```php
namespace App\Controller\V1;


use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;


#[Route('/demo/v1')]
class DemoController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'demov1')]
    public function mySpecialRouteV1(Request $request)
    {

    }
    #[Route('/other', name: 'demov1_other')]
    public function mySpecialRouteOther(Request $request)
    {

    }
}
```

and V2 controller:

```php
namespace App\Controller\V2;


use App\Controller\V1\DemoController as V1DemoController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;


#[Route('/demo/v2')]
class DemoController extends V1DemoController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'demov2')]
    public function mySpecialRouteV2(Request $request)
    {

    }
}
```

So, what is the reason behind this? As far as i can tell it's an issue with the function name. Chaning V2 function name to something else kills the override and creates the issue

Comment: I'll admit my eyes started to glass over while reading.  Not even sure what the problem is but I really can't think of any reason to extend controllers from controllers like you are doing.  Even if you get it to work it will be confusing to maintain.  If the controllers share functionality then extract the shared functionality into a service and share the service.